# Hive partition with wildcard

Tags: sql, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, impala

I am very new to partition.

Suppose I have the following table

table mytable(mytime timestamp, myname string)

where the column mytime is like this: year-month-day hour:min:sec.msec (for example,2014-12-05 08:55:59.3131)

I want to partition mytable based on year-month-day of mytime

For example,I want to make a partition for 2014-12-05

The record which has mytime like 2014-12-05 08:55:59,3131 will be in this partition.

So the query like `select * from mytable where mytime='2014-12-05%'` will search the

partition.

How can I do that in hive?

I already have data in mytable, do I need to recreate mytable and reload all the data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input

```
1997-12-31 23:59:59.999,kishore
2014-12-31 23:59:59.999999,manish

create table mytable_tmp(mytime string,myname string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ',';

load data local inpath 'input.txt'
overwrite into table mytable_tmp;



create table mytable(myname string,mytimestamp string)
PARTITIONED BY (mydate string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ',';


SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mytable PARTITION(mydate) 
SELECT myname,mytime,to_date(mytime) from  mytable_tmp;


select * from mytable where mydate='2014-12-31';



manish  2014-12-31 23:59:59.999999  2014-12-31
```

there is partition mydate which include myname and mytime according to your problem;

Comment: what if the column mytime is string (but the format is same as timestamp)?

Comment: In this example, if I want to insert (2014-12-31 11:11:11.1111,tom) to mytable, this record will be in partition 2014-12-31?

Comment: go for updated answer.let me know if you have other requirements.

Comment: if you insert (2014-12-31 11:11:11.1111,tom) to mytable, record will be partition by 2014-12-31. You also told that I want 2014-12-31 11:11:11.1111 also, so it will also store in 2014-12-31 partition.

Comment: Since I am using parquet format for mytable, it does not support timestamp type, is it possible to use only string type to achieve my requirement?

Comment: you have only replace timestamp with string, go for updated answer. If it will solve your problem, mark as right.

Comment: Thanks, it works. btw, is it possible to use distribute by to_date(my_time) in select into clause?